# Signification de « Niveau du SAS » ?

Tags: sens, expressions

J'ai vu cette expression dans cette phrase :

> Vous trouverez le coffre de la
>   résidence au niveau du SAS.

J'ai cherché sur linguee et je n'ai trouvé aucun résultat. J'ai recherché aussi avec Google et la seule référence que j'ai trouvée pour cette expression est ce [message](https://www.tripadvisor.fr/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g187172-d287194-i89063005-Campanile_Montauban-Montauban_Tarn_et_Garonne_Occitanie.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAS ne correspond pas à une abréviation connue qui puisse être précédée par *le* ou *du*. Il s'agit donc très probablement du mot ***sas*** écrit en capitales pour qu'il soit bien lisible, pour insister.

Un sas est une petite pièce de transition, un passage situé entre deux portes. Il doit donc y avoir un sas quelque part dans cette résidence, probablement juste après la porte d'entrée, où se trouve ce fameux coffre...

[TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sas/1)

> **C. −** Petit vestibule entre deux portes servant à éviter une communication directe. *Sas d'entrée.*

Comment: Peut-être certains s'imaginent-ils à tort que **sas** est un acronyme.

Comment: @XouDo Au féminin, ça existe: une [SAS](https://www.economie.gouv.fr/entreprises/societe-actions-simplifiee-SAS) mais ce n'est pas un acronyme ("ess-a-ess").